# Range em Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\Contoso\Desktop\ArquivosDoContoso.csv", Destination:=Range _
    ("$A$1"))
```

Na parte `Destination:=Range _ ("$A$1"))` tem como eu colocar o nome da tabela dinâmica?

Por Exemplo: Criei uma Tabela dinâmica com o nome `TBDados`, tem como eu fazer com que o `Destination:=Range _ ("$A$1")` seja essa tabela? Indiferente da linha que a tabela comece?

Tentei assim `Destination:=Range _ ("$TBDados$")`, porém me retorna o seguinte erro:

> O método 'Range' do objeto '_Global' falhou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
Sub Main()
    'Altere aqui de acordo com sua necessidade:
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "c:\temp\exemplo.csv"

    Dim oList As Excel.ListObject
    Dim iFF As Integer
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lCols As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim vLines() As Variant

    'Altere aqui para sua necessidade:
    Set oList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").ListObjects("Tabela1")

    oList.ListColumns(1).Range.Resize(, 4).ClearContents
    If oList.ListRows.Count > 1 Then
        oList.ListRows(2).Range.Resize(oList.ListRows.Count - 1).Delete
    End If

    iFF = FreeFile
    Open FILE_PATH For Input As #iFF
    Do Until EOF(iFF)
        Line Input #iFF, sLine
        lRows = lRows + 1
        ReDim Preserve vLines(1 To lRows)
        vLines(lRows) = sLine
    Loop
    Close #iFF

    oList.Resize oList.Range.Resize(lRows + 1)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For lRow = 1 To UBound(vLines)
        oList.ListRows(lRow).Range(1).Resize(, 4) = Split(vLines(lRow), ";")
    Next lRow
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Não funciona exatamento como eu quero. Pois tenho um arquivo `CSV` com quatro colunas e a quinta coluna eu crio no excel, que é a coluna que possui o cálculo, ao atualizar a tabela ele apaga a quinta coluna.

Comment: @MeuChapeu, acho que entendi. Apenas necessito um esclarecimento: há uma fórmula na quinta coluna?

Comment: sim, a quinta coluna por exemplo tem uma formula assim `=[@Coluna4]/1024`.

Comment: Editei o código original. Favor conferir.

Answer (score 0):

Oi,
Eu nunca usei esse método, mas para selecionar uma tabela dinâmica você pode usar o `PivotTables`. No seu caso, ex:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim tabelarange As Range

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TBDados")
Set tabelarange = pt.TableRange1 'SÓ SELECIONA A TABELA E SEU CABEÇALHO, PARA SELECIONAR OS FILTROS USE TableRange2

ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\Contoso\Desktop\ArquivosDoContoso.csv", Destination:=tabelarange)
```

Veja se funciona, infelizmente, agora não tenho como testar o `QueryTables.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

Tabelas dinâmicas são relatórios montados com base numa fonte de dados. Não é possível sobrescrevê-la.
A lógico do fluxo de montar uma relatório no Excel é:
1 - Defina uma fonte de dados
2 - Aponte uma tabela dinâmica para essa fonte de dados.

No seu caso, (1) é representado por você criar uma QueryTable numa planilha, digamos "auxiliar" (que pode ser oculta) e (2) é criar e configurar uma tabela dinâmica que aponte para essa fonte de dados.

Comment: Humm... o que tenho é uma tabela normal, o quero é atualizar essa tabela com dados de um arquivo `CSV` e a partir da tabela montar a tabela dinâmica.

Comment: Talvez você esteja buscando isso, não? http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp

Comment: É isso que quero, só que estou fazendo pelo `VBA`. Sabe como posso fazer pra atualizar a tabela sem perder referencia ou formula que estão contidas na tabela?